# How to create multicolored circle in css

Tags: html, css

I have created multicolored circle in `css`. My problem is the bottom left circle was not working.

Even if I give some colors to `.bottom-left` it was not showing.

```css
#circle-container
{
  width:100px;
  height:100px
}
.quarter
{
  width:50px;
  height:50px
}
.top-left
{
 border-top-left-radius:50px;
 background:#09f;
  float:left;
}
.top-right
{
  border-top-right-radius:50px;
  background:#666;
  float:right;
}.
bottom-left
{
  border-bottom-left-radius:50px;
  background:#782;
  float:left;
}
.bottom-right
{
  border-bottom-right-radius:50px;
  background:#333;
  float:right;
}
```

```html
<div id="circle-container">
<div class="quarter top-left"></div>
<div class="quarter top-right"></div>
<div class="quarter bottom-left"></div>
<div class="quarter bottom-right"></div>
</div>
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missed the `.` in `.bottom-left` class

You write like this

```
bottom-left
{

}
```

But You have to write like this

```
.bottom-left
{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing "." before **bottom-left**
it should be **.bottom-left**

Answer (score 1):

You gave line brake after `.` class selector

> ```
> }.
> bottom-left
> {
> ```

That's why your selector became invalid.

```css
#circle-container
{
  width:100px;
  height:100px
}
.quarter
{
  width:50px;
  height:50px
}
.top-left
{
 border-top-left-radius:50px;
 background:#09f;
  float:left;
}
.top-right
{
  border-top-right-radius:50px;
  background:#666;
  float:right;
}
.bottom-left
{
  border-bottom-left-radius:50px;
  background:#782;
  float:left;
}
.bottom-right
{
  border-bottom-right-radius:50px;
  background:#333;
  float:right;
}
```

```html
<div id="circle-container">
<div class="quarter top-left"></div>
<div class="quarter top-right"></div>
<div class="quarter bottom-left"></div>
<div class="quarter bottom-right"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    .bottom-left {
  background: #782;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50px;
  float: left;
  }
```

You have missed the . in .bottom-left class

Answer (score 1):

It's very interesting issue. I thought about making an animation to this circle with pure CSS.

Here is a solution with a **rotating** activation on hover the div:

```css
#circle-container
{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
 }
#circle-container:hover {
  -webkit-animation: spin 2s infinite linear;
  -moz-animation:    spin 2s infinite linear;
  -o-animation:      spin 2s infinite linear;
  animation:         spin 1s infinite linear;
}
@keyframes spin {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg) ;
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
.quarter
{
  width:50px;
  height:50px
}
.top-left
{
 border-top-left-radius:50px;
 background:#09f;
  float:left;
}
.top-right
{
  border-top-right-radius:50px;
  background:#666;
  float:right;
}
.bottom-left
{
  border-bottom-left-radius:50px;
  background:#782;
  float:left;
}
.bottom-right
{
  border-bottom-right-radius:50px;
  background:#333;
  float:right;
}
```

```html
<div id="circle-container">
<div class="quarter top-left"></div>
<div class="quarter top-right"></div>
<div class="quarter bottom-left"></div>
<div class="quarter bottom-right"></div>
</div>
```

And one more snippet with rotate circle once when mouse in and rotate back when mouse out

```css
#circle-container
{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  transition: transform 1s;
 }
#circle-container:hover {
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}
.quarter
{
  width:50px;
  height:50px
}
.top-left
{
 border-top-left-radius:50px;
 background:#09f;
  float:left;
}
.top-right
{
  border-top-right-radius:50px;
  background:#666;
  float:right;
}
.bottom-left
{
  border-bottom-left-radius:50px;
  background:#782;
  float:left;
}
.bottom-right
{
  border-bottom-right-radius:50px;
  background:#333;
  float:right;
}
```

```html
<div id="circle-container">
<div class="quarter top-left"></div>
<div class="quarter top-right"></div>
<div class="quarter bottom-left"></div>
<div class="quarter bottom-right"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#circle-container
{
  width:100px;
  height:100px
}
.quarter
{
  width:50px;
  height:50px
}
.top-left
{
 border-top-left-radius:50px;
 background:#09f;
  float:left;
}
.top-right
{
  border-top-right-radius:50px;
  background:#666;
  float:right;
}
.bottom-left
{
  border-bottom-left-radius:50px;
  background:#782;
  float:left;
}
.bottom-right
{
  border-bottom-right-radius:50px;
  background:#333;
  float:right;
}
```

Use This css.

Comment: Explain your code and the issue that was resolved. Don't just give a code to copy paste.

Comment: You place " . " after the end of .top-right class by mistake. I removed and placed exact before bottom-left.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.. This was best. But i have to choose the first posted answer.